# Python list: taking the brackets [] away

Tags: python, list, python-3.4

I'm trying to take away the brackets when creating a list.

Here's my code:

```
nums = [ 1,2 3,4,5]
print (nums)
```

output:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want the single row and I want commas ... I can't figure out the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4]
>>> print(*lst, sep=", ")
1, 2, 3, 4
```

Works for Python3.4 (win7), will throw a sytax error in Python2.7

Comment: How about `print(*lst, sep=', ')` -- That'll get those commas back in there like OP wants.  :-)

Comment: `from __future__ import print_function` will make this work in Python 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
print(','.join([str(num) for num in nums]))
```

Disclaimer: I only have 2.6 handy.  I'm hoping it translates directly to 3.4

Answer (score 2):

Well, you may simply create a string by [joining](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) an iterable:

```
s = ', '.join(str(n) for n in nums)
print(s)
```

Edit: casting to string is required.

Comment: `s = ",".join(map(str,nums))`

Answer (score 2):

```
In [79]: nums = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [80]: print str(nums).replace('[','').replace(']','')
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

In python 3:

```
In [3]: print (str(nums).replace('[','').replace(']',''))
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: Or:  `str(nums)[1:-1]`

Comment: @mgilson, yeah, this works too. I think it is different enough from my answer to be a separate answer. Depending on OPs desired result on nested lists, my solution would remove all the brackets.

Comment: @AshleyLynnCarpenter, you must be using python 3, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty hacky way to do exactly what you literally asked is:

```
str(lst)[1:-1]
```

But really, you shouldn't be thinking about "taking the brackets away" from a list. A list is a container and you should be thinking about doing something with the items inside it. In the case of printing them, you can do that in myriad different ways.